# For loop in R that will iterate a simple function and store results

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I have a simple function `sqrt(2 * x)` that I want to iterate `n` times using a number of different `seeds`. This is something I am going to do often so I wanted to create a general function The code I have so far is:

```
iterator <- function(FUNC, seeds = -10:10, n = 100) {
    results <- matrix(nrow = n,
                      ncol = length(seeds))
    results[1, ] <- seeds

    for (i in 2:n) {
        results[i, ] <- FUNC(results[i - 1, ])
    }
    results
}
```

I then create my function `f`:

```
f <- function(x) sqrt(2 * x)
```

And then call `iterator` (using different args to avoid `NaN` errors and limit the output):

```
iterator(f, seeds = seq(0, 20, by = .5), n = 20)
```

This works OK, but I have two questions:

1. Is there a simpler/more elegant way to achieve this? I have a feeling that this will work alright for such a simple function but might be slow with something more complex.
2. At the end I simply print `results`, but I would like to be able to assign the output to a variable (e.g. `myresults <- iterator(f)`). But when I try that `myresults` just ends up as a `NULL`. How do I pass the matrix as an output from the function?

Comment: In order to get the results matrix as an output (that you can assign to a variable) you need to use return(results) at the end of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sapply instead of a loop:

```
iterator <- function(n, seeds) {
  res      <- matrix(NA, nrow=n, ncol=length(seeds))
  res[1, ] <- seeds
  sapply(2:n, FUN=function(x) { res[x,] <<- sqrt(2 * res[x-1,]) })
  return(res)
}
```